# java application for stand alone execution and as a jar library

Tags: java, jar

I want to create a java application that can be executed in two ways.
As a standard stand alone application, using main(args[]), and with in any java application using a jar, imported to that other application as an external library.

The problem i am facing is that i want to use the same function on both cases. This is causing be error, since i have to declare static the methods and variables when executed as stand alone application but as not static when i need to access it from an other application.

I have never done that before, so i am not 100% sure that this is a real problem. my past projects were always static all the way.
I am guessing i could bread my code in two classes, having the main on one and every other method on the other and use it as it was a separate project. 
Is this a correct approach?

Comment: You don't have to create two identical classes, one without the main. It can all go in the one class. Can you add the code to your question, it'll help solve the issue. You shouldn't use static methods, create an instance of the class and then call the functions from the instance.

Comment: I didnt mean to use two identical classes. one class would have the main and any other method i have to use, and the methods that are shared for both cases would be on the other class, calling them as objects

Comment: Oh, I see. See the answer from duffymo below, he shows you how to approach it.

Comment: main method can be called by another class: see answer below.

Comment: Why would you want to?  I think it's confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try writing it like this:

```
public class DoubleDuty {
    // This is the main method executed using java -jar
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        DoubleDuty dd = new DoubleDuty();
        dd.complexApplication();
    }

    public void complexApplication() {
        // This can be executed by others who import this JAR.
    }
}
```

Comment: so i am executing the methods as being a different class. right! didnt think of that.

Answer (score 0):

only one public static main() is necessary in you new class.

The main is always static, but you class can have instances.

You can call it by another class:

```
public class Class1 {
public static void main(String args[])
    {
    System.out.println("Class1 BEGINS !");
    }
}

public class Class2 {
    public static void main(String args[])
        {
        Class1.main(args);
        // or that
        Class1.main(new String[0]); beware if inside main , you read args !
        }
```

}

when you compile your jar as standalone, set the start to the other class:
Lauch Configuration => set Class1 or Class2

Comment: I am not sure i follow. will this be executable from a third class using the created jar? from what i know methods need to be non static in order to be loaded in such a manner.

Comment: your question was to have a function (main), used standalone, and from another app. The simplest answer is: yes: you can call from another (just choose the good class to start, when building your jar). After, you can also use subfunctions, ...

Comment: I didnt ask how to start main from an other class. All i wanted is use the main of a class when executed from the terminal, and be able to use all other methods from a different class. Havent tried it, but I dont think this solution would work

Comment: everything is possible. The main method is static. And you can use it in the main program or from other classes (see my code, which works well). Otherwise, you can have non-static method, which of course can be used inside or outside the class. In fact the question is unrelated with "main" method. It's about static or not methods.